# Handling HTTP 404 bad request error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am currently building a website and I want to add the `HTTP 404 not found` Error page. I designed the bad request page and its link is this, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/badr.cshtml
```

The problem is, I want to show the contents of this page on every invalid request without redirecting to that link. For example, if I type `www.mysite.com/noexistingpage`, the contents of `badr.cshtml` should load without redirecting to it.

And for your information, I am using Webmatrix2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do this via the web.config and the custom errors section.

http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-setup-custom-404s-for-iis-and-asp-net-through-web-config/

Comment: one thing it could be is your web.config is not valid because of the updates you made based on the link, have you made sure it is valid?